# Interaction de langues

Tags: comparaison-de-langues

Je veux bien améliorer mon français, surtout à l'écrit. Mais je ne sais pas trop comment travailler dessus.

Est-ce que recopier un texte littéraire ou un article peut nous habituer à utiliser le bon français?

Le français est ma deuxième langue étrangère et j'ai remarqué que l'anglais (ma première langue étrangère) et ma langue maternelle (le malaisien) ont influencé la façon dont je m'exprime, que ce soit à l'oral ou à l'écrit. D'un côté, ça peut être vu comme une chose positive car il y a des échanges entre ces trois langues, mais d'un autre côté, c'est devenu plus difficile d'utiliser un français, disons *correct*.

Est-ce mieux d'isoler ces langues pour qu'elles *se développent* indépendamment, ou est-ce que des échanges entre les langues qu'on a apprises doivent être encouragés ?

(Je pense que le mieux c'est de se retrouver au milieu. Par contre, j'ai toujours l'impression que les gens qu'on considère bilingue ont réussi à développer les langues dans leurs propres *milieux* ce qui leur permet de mieux traiter ces langues avec les différentes nuances ou cultures qui existent.)

Comment: S'il vous plaît, consultez la [FAQ](http://french.stackexchange.com/faq#quelles-questions-puis-je-poser-ici-): « Ce site est un site de questions-réponses, et pas un forum de discussions ouvertes. Merci d'éviter les questions qui ne font qu'ouvrir un débat ou auxquelles une réponse raisonnable couvrirait un livre entier. » Donnez des réponses argumentées aux questions posées (éventuellement en fournissant références), ou elles seront supprimées.

Comment: Note: Pour les discussions, il y a un salon qui n'attend que vous pour reprendre un peu d'activité. C'est par [ici](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/french-language-and-usage).

Comment: Merci pour cet avertissement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suite de ces excellents conseils :

Français incapable de faire un thème, je suis absolument incapable de soutenir une conversation anglaise, je me contente du Globish (Global English / English Airport).

La version, est plus facile, et permet d'augmenter son vocabulaire en recherchant un mot (dans un ou plusieurs dictionnaires) et en prenant le temps de regarder (souvent *en s'obligeant*) toutes ses acceptions, ses racines, ses usages habituels, ses homonymes, ses synonymes, les contextes d'usage…
et de refaire cette même lecture le lendemain.

C'est un exercice quotidien sur un ou deux mots : il ne doit pas être fatiguant : ne pas se priver « *d'avoir envie de* » découvrir, de connaître.

Lorsque je suis professionnellement obligé de rédiger, petit à petit, j'ai pu affiner mes expressions, sans toutefois pouvoir traduire les phrases complexes qui me viennent naturellement en langue maternelle.

Bravo : Apprendre le français, qui comporte beaucoup d'exceptions, de complexités de nuances peut maintenir votre ouverture au monde tout au long de votre vie… et bravo encore pour avoir compris qu'une langue construit son locuteur.

Je vous souhaite de pouvoir évoquer naturellement vos émotions dans toutes les langues que vous allez maîtriser… avec une petite préférence (chauvine) pour le français.

*P.S.* : Je ne peux m'empêcher de citer le recueille de poème « Paroles » de Prévert qui sous son apparente simplicité fait passer beaucoup de la langue française.
Bien sûr, écouter Brassens, Barbara, Brel, Joe Dassin, Aznavour, Piaf, Ferrat et beaucoup d'autres vous feront découvrir des textes classiques contemporains qui peuvent être mémorisés plus facilement avec l'aide de la mélodie. Ensuite vous serez capable de choisir ce qui vous convient et vous nous ferez par part de vos trouvailles.

Answer (score 4):

La première chose à développer à mon avis, c'est la lecture.
Lire beaucoup, des classiques, du contemporain, des article de presse...

C'est en tout cas la méthode que j'essaye d'appliquer pour améliorer mon anglais.

Par la suite, l'écriture peut être une bonne pratique pour justement mettre en pratique ce qi a été lu. Mais pas uniquement de la recopie.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question.

Comment: Je pense que ça répond à la première question..

je peux dire que c'est ce que je fais actuellement mais je me méfie aussi de _la quantité volumétrique_ que j'ai parcouru.

C'est un long chemin, mais je suis content de voir mes progression de jours en jours.
 
En tout cas, merci à vous.

Answer (score 2):

Je vois deux questions:

(1) Je pense que c'est une bonne idée... en tout cas, ça ne fera pas de mal.  A l'école, on apprenait beaucoup de textes par coeur.  Il me semble que cet exercice était très utile.  En tout cas, de temps en temps, des bribes de phrases me reviennent à l'esprit et améliorent mon style à l'écrit, en français tout comme en anglais.

(2) Je ne comprends pas exactement ce que tu entends par «échanges» entre les langues. Il me semble que c'est plus difficile d'apprendre une langue dans un milieu multilingue, mais qu'avec un peu d'effort on peut surmonter la difficulté.  Par example, j'ai des collègues anglophones qui ont vécu à Montréal 2-3 ans, et ont appris le français et d'autres, montréalais anglophones de souche, qui ont un niveau de français vraiment minimal.

En fait, je ne devrais rien dire : c'est toi qui devrait donner des leçons d'apprentissage de langues.  Ton français me semble être à un très bon niveau, et tu nous dis que c'est ta troisième langue!  Bravo!

Comment: Ce que j'entends par "échanges" était la communication entre des langues. Je vois les langues que j'ai apprises comme une entité, un individu qui a ses propres caractères, ses mémoires, son histoire et surtout ses cultures distincts. 

En tout cas, je vous remercie. Je ne peux plus me faire prendre par l'administrateur.

Answer (score 1):

Entièrement d'accord avec Atorgael. Pratique, pratique, pratique! Côté oral, je conseille toujours les dessins animés plutôt que les séries télévisées ou les films au début, surtout si tu n'arrives pas à lire les sous-titres assez vite (en outre, les sous-titres ne correspondent pas toujours à ce qui est réellement dit!). L'intérêt est que les dessins animés ont souvent un débit plus lent que les séries avec des acteurs physiques. Ils m'ont beaucoup aidé à améliorer ma compréhension orale de l'anglais au début.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à la question.

Comment: Bonne idée. C'est quand même étonnant que je me suis pas penché sérieusement à ça, surtout que j'aime les mangas.
Merci!

Answer (score 1):

@cl-r

Justement pourquoi il me semble inévitable que les langues qu'on a maîtrisées, surtout notre langue maternelle, aient une influence considérable sur la langue étrangère qu'on apprend.

Les phrases complexes sont déjà disponible au préalable dans notre langue maternelle lorsque'on apprend une nouvelle langue.

Du coup, ça nous tente de faire référence à notre langue maternelle(surtout) pour étudier la nouvelle langue.

Donc, je me demande, même s'il est tout à fait impossible de faire table rase sur nos consciences et ensuite apprendre la nouvelle langue, il y a probablement un moyen d'imiter la façon dont les enfants apprennent une langue.

Je crois que c'est quand même un miracle que les enfants ont cette capacité d'apprentissage. Donc qu'est-ce qui se passe lorsqu'on grandit qui fait qu'on est moins capable par rapport aux ces enfants?

Bon, peut être certains entre vous vont dire que, au lieu de réfléchir à ces questions, n'est-il pas mieux de 'pratiquer,pratiquer et pratiquer'. =)

Comment: L'apprentissage des enfants se fait par suppression de connexions pré-établies entre les neurones, il réussi a en établir d'autre quelquefois : plus un axone est stimulé, plus il a de myéline, et plus il est rapide. Cette malléabilité s'arrête vers 26 ans. - Le cerveau qui peut mémoriser alors deux cents fois moins de mots par jour, adopte alors d'autres stratégies, il cherche dans ses neurones ceux qui ont été stimulés par une émotion, retrouve le mot (appris jeune) et peut le *coder* dans un autre langage. - Mais il aura beaucoup de difficulté à s'adapter à une structure mentale étrangère.

Answer (score 0):

@afiqjohari:
Pour l'apprentissage d'une langue, il faut se référer aux dernières découvertes des sciences cognitives : les quelques milliards de neurones interconnectés reçus en héritages font un travail de déconnexion/reconnexion pour favoriser les réactions les mieux adaptées à l'environnement.

Selon un neurologue entendu récemment à la radio, on peut considérer le cerveau comme un outils capable de valoriser les statistiques de nos perceptions et de nos émotions : il s'agit ici du fondement du langage, l'origine d'une langue avant sa formulation, la base de connaissance émotionnelle et raisonnable sur laquelle toute communication s'appuie.

Les capacités de mémorisation s'érodent à partir de 26 ans.
Il n'est donc pas question de chercher la fontaine de jouvence, ni de vouloir entrer en compétition avec les mémoires magnétiques.

Je me souviendrai toujours de mon ami vietnamien qui me disait souvent : "vous, les occidentaux n'avez pas la même structure mentale", mais qui par la vivacité de ses réactions, un sourire pouvait contrôler le déroulement d'une conversation, aussi bien technique que philosophique.
On peut connaître une langue sans savoir résoudre les problèmes de traduction.

Il faut donc une curiosité envers l'Autre, l'envie de découvrir des univers proches.
Pour y arriver pas d'autre moyen que d'être soi-même, pierre de touche, référence intuitive qui va utiliser le rôle pour interpréter le même personnage dans des contextes différents.

Acteur sans talent, je me contente des seconds rôles lorsque je ne peux occuper celui de figurant. Les grands talents ont un rôle de passeur.
Souvent les interprètes ont vécu dans dans l'autre pays pour connaître tout ce qui ne peut être formulé par écrit, tout ce qui constitue la saveur d'une langue.

C'est donc un mouvement d'écoute de nos émotions, d'attention de tous les sens qui permet à notre cerveaux de maîtriser les rôles qu'il à a jouer dans des sociétés différentes.

Comment: J'ai l'impression d'être éclairé en lisant votre commentaire. Vous me rappelez l'envie d'aller découvrir ailleurs au lieu de se pencher étroitement sur soi. En effet, le soi se trouve aussi dans l'Autre. 
Merci pour ce petit rappel.